# How to add JSON array of array to model

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

Currently I'm doing an API to fire JSON array of array to mysql. But I don't know how to receive the data to the model class when fire the API. I tried to use ArrayList[] but still cannot make it.

Here is the data that I need to fire.

[image]

[image]

Controller :

```
//insert Trip
    @RequestMapping(value = "inserting", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestBody ArrayList<Trips[]>[] c) {
        LOGGER.debug("start insert to database...");
        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
             //trip = c[i];
            tripsService.saveTrips(trip); 
        }   
        LOGGER.debug("insert successfull...");
        return c.toString();
    }
```

Comment: can you switch the json structure you have?

Comment: cannot is fix only can json array of array

Comment: try doing in your controller ArrayList<Trips[]>[] to  ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>

Comment: in order you can map to this Trips Object you need to have a json structure: key -> value, you have no it, so it will not be able to map

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> able to work but how to convert it to Trips model class? bcsz i need to .save(Trips).

Comment: you have to iterate over each elements is coming, then instantiate a Trips object and setting the values using setter methods, i think it is a manual process

Comment: Trips trip = new Trips();
trip = c.get(0);
for(int i=0;i<c.size();i++){
 tripsService.saveTrips(trip);
   
}

Comment: here is the next step that I need to do

Comment: yes, something like you mention, I have just put a likely solution

Comment: Is this API and client sending it written by you or it is a public API?

Comment: is write by me not public API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it  is not  possible to map directly to the object you want, for the I suggest you switch the incoming data type, something like:

```
public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestBody ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> c) {
```

Then, in the controller doing a iteration over each element you have in the array, instantiate the Trips Object, doing use of setter methods,  set the values of Trips object

```
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
    List<Object> tripIncoming = c.get(i);
    Trips trip = new Trips();
    trip.setPropertie1(tripIncoming.get(0))
    trip.setPropertie2(tripIncoming.get(1))

    ....
    .... rest properties
    tripsService.saveTrips(trip); 
}
```

Comment: but I have 150++ field to set for the Trips class, any other dynamic way to do it?

Comment: do you mean the Trip class has 150 fields?

Comment: Actually, I got another model class with 150 ++ field for another project. Bcsz of asking question on here, so I just use the Trip class with less field to try it out with the same method

Comment: I think you can create a custom method, where you can set the different properties, perhaps you have to write much code

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to pass Array in JSON format. You should put one wrapper class over you entity trips. something like:

```java
class MyTrips {
    List<Trips> trips = new ArrayList<>();
    //Getter and Setter 
}
```

At the end receive something like:

```java
//insert Trip
    @RequestMapping(value = "inserting", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestBody MyTrips myTrips) {
        ArrayList<Trips[]>[] c = myTrips.getTrips();
        LOGGER.debug("start insert to database...");
        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
             //trip = c[i];
            tripsService.saveTrips(trip); 
        }   
        LOGGER.debug("insert successfull...");
        return c.toString();
    }
```

Comment: but I get this error "cannot convert from List<Trips> to ArrayList<Trips[]>[]" at myTrips.getTrips()